# Multiplying float With Large Numbers Simply Appending Numbers Together

Tags: c, variables, type-promotion

I am attempting to convert float values of MB, GB, and TB to bytes, but I  am having issues multiplying a base amount of space (say, 500 GB) by a large value to convert them.

I believe it is a data type error, yet I can't seem to figure it out. I tried looking at the order of promotion, yet following that logic didn't seem to work. When my program tries to multiply 500 * 10000000000, I get 1000000000499999997952.000000 (or something similar depending on variable types).

```
long factor = 10000000000;
float capacity = 500;
double result = capacity * factor;
fprint("%lf", result);
```

It should output 5000000000000, but I get 1000000000499999997952.000000 instead. I don't think the variable types are right, but nothing I try seems to aid this issue.

Comment: What happens if you change `capacity` to a double?

Comment: It outputs 1000000000500000000000.000000. The final portion is what I want, but I'm not sure how to get rid of the 1000... before it.

Comment: It seems there's more going on than the code sample if your question. Maybe you forgot that somewhere else you're printing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long long factor = 10000000000;
    float capacity = 500.0f;
    double result = capacity * factor;
    double result1 = (double)capacity * factor;

    printf("result = %f\n result1 = %f\n", result, result1);

    return 0;
}
```

and the result

```
result = 4999999913984.000000
result1 = 5000000000000.000000
```